# Cbind or rbind a unique object to multiple objects

Tags: r

I have a single object `unique_object` that I would like to bind to multiple objects `object1, object2, object3 e.tc...`, without transforming the multiple objects into a single list and I cannot figure out how I would do it:

I have tried passing cbind a list of the different objects, but I believe `r` interprets it as a single object comprised of all of those objects:

```
cbind(list(object1,object2,object3,object4 e.t.c... ), unique_object)
```

`unique_object` and `object1, object2`, etc. are of the same length.

Comment: What exactly are these object? Matrices? Data.frames? vectors? What class of object to you expect after the cbind?

Comment: They could be any of these, and are easily converted between them.

Comment: @user1987097 Sorry , I miss read the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
lapply(list(object1,object2,object3,object4, ... ), cbind, unique_object)
```

This will return a list where unique_object is cbinded to each item in the original list.

Comment: This does it but without assigning anything.

Comment: +1! maybe you need a `list2env` step (even it is not recommended )

Comment: Well it returns an appropriate list, you can do with it as you like. R doesn't pass around references do you can't change the object in place. I guess I really don't understand what you want.

Comment: I'd like to keep the objects as lists, but unique_object bound to each them.

Comment: @user1987097 Well, just replace the original list with the newly returned list. If you need any more help, please edit your question to include a specific [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) which makes it clear what the input and what the desired output is so we can test and evaluate suggestions.